# Can I remove query params of the current page without removing component state React Router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I want to remove query param `?error=true` from my current screen before that I need to store that information in state. but if I use props.history.replace, The state information of my current component will loss. Is there any way to remove query param without re-rendering with react router

Comment: did you try window.replaceState() ? Please try this once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't check this with React but I have tried it with Angular,

You can create the current url like this and remove the query params that you want. If you have many query params than param `error`, you may need to get them and dynamically remove error param and add it to the end of the below variable

```
const updatedUrl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname
```

Now you can use,

```
window.history.pushState({path:updatedUrl},'',updatedUrl);
```

**UPDATE**
Here I tried it with React

```
function useQuery() {
  return new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search); //useLocation from react-router-dom
}

export default function App() {
  const [err, setErr] = useState(null);

  let query = useQuery();

  useEffect(function() {
    setErr(query.get("error"));
    const updatedUrl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname;
    window.history.pushState({path:updatedUrl},'',updatedUrl);
  }, [query])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>error = {err}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```